# Can't use props for styled components with emotion-js and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, emotion, emotion-js

Here's my very simple component:

```js
import React, { ReactChild, ElementType } from 'react'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

type WrapperPropsType = {
  size?: SizeType
}

type ButtonPropsType = {
  as?: ElementType<any>,
  size?: SizeType,
  children?: ReactChild
}

const Wrapper = styled.button<WrapperPropsType>((props: WrapperPropsType) => ({
  fontSize: FontSize[props.size],
}))

const Button = ({ as, size, children }: ButtonPropsType) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper as={as} size={size}>
        { children }
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

My `.tsconfig`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node", "@emotion/react"],
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "build",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```

But on compile I'm getting next error:

> Error: src/components/Button/Button.tsx(18,30): semantic error TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type '{ theme?: Theme; as?: ElementType; } & Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes, HTMLButtonElement>, "form" | ... 265 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture">
> & { ...; }'.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help

Packages versions:
`@emotion/react` version: 11.1.2
`@emotion/styled` version: 11.0.0
`typescript` version: 4.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by replacing `rollup-plugin-typescript2` with `@rollup/plugin-typescript`. There were no errors in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `size` in `WrapperPropsType` but not using it. Add it and it will work

```
const Button = ({ as, size, children }: ButtonPropsType & WrapperPropsType) => {
```

Comment: I also had `size` in ButtonPropsType, so it is already defined, and adding `& WrapperPropsType` doesn't change anything, unfortunately

Comment: Check if you're using the proper `ButtonPropsType`. Coz `{ theme?: Theme; as?: ElementType; } & Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes, HTMLButtonElement>` and `{
  as?: ElementType<any>,
  size?: SizeType,
  children?: ReactChild
}` are not same